# Hot Neutral Wire- Dead Outlet and Light

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

The wiring in question wasn't touched in over a year and worked fine. I say this because the problem came up suddenly without any obvious cause except maybe for a strong windy rainstorm. It might be irrelevant though.

Problem: The power to an outdoor flood light and outdoor receptacle stopped working. The circuit is a light switch then the light and outlet in parallel to each other. The outlet is a GFCI installed in a damp/wet rated receptacle. The cover was open during the storm because something is plugged into it. Note: I tested the exterior light by building a power cord and plugging it into another outlet and it works.

Investigation: The outlet and light will not work. Using a non contact voltage tester, the hot and neutral at the outlet and light have current (for this I will just say "beep"). The outlet and the light get power from the same source so I disconnected the all wires from black and white wires coming thru the exterior wall from the switch. These two wires both beeped.

On the interior there is a light switch that controls power to these 2 outside objects. I flipped the light switch off and both black and white did not beep.

The light switch is a 2 gang with another light switch next to it.

I removed the cover plate and the other light switch is a 3 way switch. It is connected to the exterior light switch by the black wire.
[image]
[image: Picture 2]

When the interior switch is turned on, the white and black exterior wires beep. When the interior switch is off, only the black beeps.

However in all cases the exterior light does not work. But the interior lights connected to the interior switch work just fine.

Help!

Comment: This is why "in-use covers" are now mandatory.  On the tripping GFCI receptacle, are there any wires attached to the LOAD terminals? Wher do they go?

Comment: Sounds like the GFI may be damaged. Remove all wires making note where they were attached and check voltage with a multimeter, rather than the contact tester. You may be picking up phantom voltage.

Comment: Just to clarify the GFI is the last item in the circuit. Disconnecting the GFCI doesn't fix the issue. The flood light alone connected to B-W-G coming from the inside switch will not turn on.

Comment: Update- tested the outlet with a tester. It lights up Off-Red-Green (Hot-GND Reverse)

Not sure what this means because it's hooked up the same way it was for a year

Comment: Hot/ground reverse means the hot wire is connected to the ground terminal of the GFCI, and the ground wire is connected to the hot terminal. Despite "same way for a year", that's wrong and needs to be fixed. It is _possible_ that the problem is a failed GFCI, but with that reading in the tester I'm pretty confident you have it disconnected instead, or in addition.

Comment: @keshlam it was working for a year so it was right at some point. I'll double check tomorrow.

Comment: Misconnected, not disconnected. Auto-incorrect strikes again.... Also, are there _three_ wires connected to that switch's terminals, not counting ground? If so you're looking at a three-way circuit (control from either of two switches) and things get more complex. Note that someone mucking with the wires at the switch could cause an error detected by the outlet tester...

Comment: @keshlam yes there are 3 but I believe one of them is providing power to the adjacent 3 way switch (it's just a small jumper wire)

I disconnected everything from the switch except incoming the power black wire and the black wire going to the outside light. I left the white neutrals joined together. I attached a new outlet on the outside and got the same error that Hot and Ground and reversed.

I traced the incoming power to the switch and the wire leads to multiple outlets in my basement. All those outlets are working just fine. I am not sure where to go now.